# EC2 Spot Instance Termination & Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I know that the termination notice is made available via the meta-data url and that I can do something similar to

```
if requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time").status_code == 200
```

in order to determine if the notice has been posted. I run a Python service on my Spot Instances that:

1. Loops over long polling SQS Queues
2. If it gets a message, it pauses polling and works on the payload.
3. Working on the payload can take 5-50 minutes.
4. Working on the payload will involve spawning a threadpool of up to 50 threads to handle parallel uploading of files to S3, this is the majority of the time spent working on the payload.
5. Finally, remove the message from the queue, rinse, repeat.

The work is idempotent, so if the same payload runs multiple times, I'm out the processing time/costs, but will not negatively impact the application workflow.

I'm searching for an elegant way to now also poll for the termination notice every five seconds in the background. As soon as the termination notice appears, I'd like to immediately release the message back to the SQS queue in order for another instance to pick it up as quickly as possible.

As a bonus, I'd like to shutdown the work, kill off the threadpool, and have the service enter a stasis state. If I terminate the service, supervisord will simply start it back up again.

Even bigger bonus! Is there not a python module available that simplifies this and just works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code to demonstrate how a thread can be used to poll for the Spot instance termination. It first starts up a polling thread, which would be responsible for checking the http endpoint.

Then we create pool of fake workers *(mimicking real work to be done)* and starts running the pool. Eventually the polling thread will kick in *(about 10 seconds into execution as implemented)* and kill the whole thing.

To prevent the script from continuing to work after Supervisor restarts it, we would simply put a check at the beginning of the `__main__` and if the termination notice is there we sleep for 2.5 minutes, which is longer than that notice lasts before the instance is shutdown.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import Queue
import random
import time
import sys
import os

class Instance_Termination_Poll(threading.Thread):
    """
    Sleep for 5 seconds and eventually pretend that we then recieve the
    termination event

    if requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time").status_code == 200
    """

    def run(self):
        print("Polling for termination")
        while True:
            for i in range(30):
                time.sleep(5)
                if i==2:
                    print("Recieve Termination Poll!")
                    print("Pretend we returned the message to the queue.")
                    print("Now Kill the entire program.")
                    os._exit(1)
            print("Well now, this is embarassing!")

class ThreadPool:
    """
    Pool of threads consuming tasks from a queue
    """

    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.num_threads = num_threads
        self.errors = Queue.Queue()
        self.tasks = Queue.Queue(self.num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads):
            Worker(self.tasks, self.errors)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        """
        Add a task to the queue
        """
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        """
        Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue
        """
        try:
            while True:
                if self.tasks.empty() == False:
                    time.sleep(10)
                else:
                    break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Ctrl-c received! Kill it all with Prejudice..."
            os._exit(1)

        self.tasks.join()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    """
    Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue
    """

    def __init__(self, tasks, error_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.errors = error_queue
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
            try:
                func(*args, **kargs)
            except Exception, e:
                print("Exception " + str(e))
                error = {'exception': e}
                self.errors.put(error)

            self.tasks.task_done()

def do_work(n):
    """
    Sleeps a random ammount of time, then creates a little CPU usage to
    mimic some work taking place.
    """
    for z in range(100):
        time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))
        print "Thread ID: {} working.".format(threading.current_thread())
        for x in range(30000):
            x*n
        print "Thread ID: {} done, sleeping.".format(threading.current_thread())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_threads = 30

    # Start up the termination polling thread
    term_poll = Instance_Termination_Poll()
    term_poll.start()

    # Create our threadpool
    pool = ThreadPool(num_threads)
    for y in range(num_threads*2):
        pool.add_task(do_work, n=y)

    # Wait for the threadpool to complete
    pool.wait_completion()
```